# Creating subclasses to handle "base-cases"

Tags: java, class

Every now and then I see code where the programmer has extended a certain class to handle "base cases". For example, if I were creating a `Tuple` class to represent a tuple of integers, I would have something like

```
class Tuple {
    private int[] values;

    ...
}
```

But some people will extend `Tuple` to accommodate a few base-cases, such as a tuple of length 0, 1 or 2:

```
class Tuple0 extends Tuple {
    ...
}

class Tuple1 extends Tuple {
    private int value1;

    ...
}

class Tuple2 extends Tuple {
    private int value1;
    private int value2;

    ...
}
```

Of course, the methods (denoted by `...`) of each `TupleN` class will be much simpler than those of the generic `Tuple` class. So, my question is: is there any benefit to this type of practice? If so, when and why; if not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big drawback of this approach is that it leads to increased code size and less maintainable code. A potential advantage is possibly increased performance, but you really need to profile to make sure.

Personally, I wouldn't do this.

Comment: Agreed. However, just because it comes up quite frequently, I *might* be tempted to create a Pair class for a two-tuple, with a constructor taking two arguments. I wouldn't override any of the methods, but I'd probably add a getLeft() and getRight() method, or whatever you would want to call the accessors for the two values.